# How to multiply different numbers in specific column in specific rows?

Tags: awk

I want to multiply 5, 4, 3 in the 2nd column (1st 5 rows), (6th to 8th rows) and (9th to 10th rows) respectively.

I can only multiply one number using below command

```
awk '{print $1, $2*5, $3,$4}' defect > out.txt
```

Input:

```
# "Frame" "Timestep" "WignerSeitz.interstitial_count" "WignerSeitz.vacancy_count"
 1 100 1 1 
 2 200 1 1 
 3 300 1 1 
 4 400 1 1 
 5 500 1 1 
 6 600 1 1 
 7 700 2 2 
 8 800 2 2 
 9 900 2 2 
 10 1000 2 2
```

Expected output:

```
# "Frame" "Timestep" "WignerSeitz.interstitial_count" "WignerSeitz.vacancy_count"
 1 500 1 1 
 2 1000 1 1 
 3 1500 1 1 
 4 2000 1 1 
 5 2500 1 1 
 6 2400 1 1 
 7 2800 2 2 
 8 3200 2 2 
 9 2700 2 2 
 10 3000 2 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with `NR` = Line Number Variable in awk

```
awk 'NR<=5{$2=$2*5};NR>5 && NR<=8{$2=$2*4};NR>8 && NR<=10{$2=$2*3};1' file1
1 500 1 1
2 1000 1 1
3 1500 1 1
4 2000 1 1
5 2500 1 1
6 2400 1 1
7 2800 2 2
8 3200 2 2
9 2700 2 2
10 3000 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `if...else` statements and `NR` to get a row number.

`awk '{if (NR==1) {print $1, $2*5, $3, $4, $5} else if (NR <= 6) {print $1, $2*5, $3, $4, $5} else if (NR<=9) {print $1, $2*4, $3, $4, $5} else {print $1, $2*3, $3, $4, $5}}' defect > out.txt`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the first field is the control for the multiplier (as the row number is affected by any header row), you could match against $1:

```
awk '$1 ~ /1$|2|3|4|5/ {$2*=5}; $1 ~ /6|7|8/ {$2*=4}; $1 ~ /9|10/ {$2*=3};1' defect 
# "Frame" "Timestep" "WignerSeitz.interstitial_count" "WignerSeitz.vacancy_count"
1 500 1 1
2 1000 1 1
3 1500 1 1
4 2000 1 1
5 2500 1 1
6 2400 1 1
7 2800 2 2
8 3200 2 2
9 2700 2 2
10 3000 2 2
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you very much. it is working well. but is there any way that we can use the range like 1-5 or less than 6 not like the specific line.

Comment: Yes. The following code works for me:

    awk '($1>=1 && $1<=5) {$2*=5}; ($1>=6 && $1<=8) {$2*=4}; ($1>=9 && $1<=10) {$2*=3};1' defect

Answer (score 0):

Done by using awk-if-else if-else condition

```
awk '{if (NR<6){print $1,5*$2,$3,$4}else if(NR>5 && NR<9){print $1,4*$2,$3,$4}else {print $1,3*$2,$3,$4}}' p
```

output

```
1 500 1 1
2 1000 1 1
3 1500 1 1
4 2000 1 1
5 2500 1 1
6 2400 1 1
7 2800 2 2
8 3200 2 2
9 2700 2 2
10 3000 2 2
```